# get text within div including span using xpath

Tags: jquery, html, css, xpath

I have some html like this:

```
<div id="uniqueID">here <span>is some</span> text</div>
```

I'd like to get "here is some text" using xpath
with jQuery I can use

```
$("#uniqueID").text()
# returns "here is some text"
```

but with xpath

```
html.xpath('//div[@id="uniqueID"]/text()').extract()
# returns [u'here ', u' text']
```

and

```
html.xpath('//div[@id="uniqueID"]/span/text()').extract()
# returns [u'is some']
```

Any idea how I can get all the text with xpath, or css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `//div[@id="uniqueID"]/concat(text()[1], span/text(), text()[2])`

Or you could use `string()` instead of `text()`, depends on XPath version.

Comment: this would work for this specific example, in my case I have an unknown number of spans inside a div. jQuery's text() function ignores the spans, is there any alternative. Should I maybe just select the div, and then use something in python to parse it?

Comment: string() gives Invalid XPath: ./string()

Comment: yea I already had the element selected, anything with string() says Invalid XPath: ...

Comment: AH! I just did .xpath('string()') on the already selected object and that worked. Still learning xpath a bit. Thanks so much!